# javascript regex to validate alphanumeric text with spaces and reject special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm not an expert with regex but tried my hand with validating a field that allows alphanumeric data with spaces but not any other special characters. Where linkTitle is the name of the variable to test i tried with the following regex in my conditional

```
/[^A-Za-z\d\s]/.test(linkTitle)
/[^A-Za-z0-9\s]/.test(linkTitle)
/[^A-Za-z\d ]/.test(linkTitle)
```

and none of these worked... i'm curious to know what went wrong with the regex using \s which seemingly refers whitespaces and what would be the apt regex to fit the bill.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: When you say `spaces` do you mean `' '` characters, or do you mean to include all the other space chars like `'\f', '\t'` etc?

Comment: What are your pass fail conditions? write up a simple unit-test.

Comment: let's say for the moment any whitespace like \t \v \f is acceptable for the input

Comment: All three of your regexes are perfectly good and will return TRUE if `linkTitle` contains one invalid char (and will thus return FALSE if it has only valid chars). You need to elaborate when you say: _"... and none of these worked"_ Please provide the failing code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you want to match the beginning of the string *once*, then use the Positive Closure—one or more—of your letters, spaces or digits, then the end of the string.

```
/^[A-Za-z\d\s]+$/.test(linkTitle)
```

Tested with:

```
var reg = /^[A-Za-z\d\s]+$/;
["Adam", "Ada m", "A1dam", "A!dam", 'sdasd 213123&*&*&'].forEach(function (str) {
    console.log(reg.test(str + "\n"));
});
```

Shows `true`, `true`, `true`, `false`, `false`

---

Or if you want to allow empty strings, you could use the same RegEx but with the Kleene Closure—zero or more—of letters, digits or spaces

```
var regAllowEmpty = /^[A-Za-z\d\s]*$/;
["", "Adam", "Ada m", "A1dam", "A!dam", 'sdasd 213123&*&*&'].forEach(function (str) {
    console.log(regAllowEmpty.test(str + "\n"));
});
```

note that `forEach` will not work on older browsers - this is just for testing

Comment: This will return true for any input. Try one or more instead

Comment: @missingno - I was banging my head against the wall testing this trying to figure out what was wrong - thank you!

Comment: @AdamRackis i tried the following string with and it passed through the validation when it shouldn't have
var linkTitle='sdasd 213123&*&*&';
/^[A-Za-z\d\s]+$/.test(linkTitle);
this is proving to be quite a testing of patience.. :'(

Comment: @optimusprime619 - are you sure?  I just tested that same string and it failed.

Comment: @optimusprime619 - I updated my test to include that string - it fails like it should

Comment: @AdamRackis checked it again... the thing was cached... thank goodness it works like a charm....awesome..thanks so much all for helping me through a bad day!! merry christmas in advance to all of you...

Comment: @optimusprime619 - Merry Christmas to you too.  Glad it worked

Comment: @optimusprime619 - btw - your question gave me my 400th upvote for the JavaScript tag - so thanks for that :)

Comment: @AdamRackis happy that i did the honours ;)

Answer (score 1):

Any of your three regex here will match any single character that is **not** one between `[`and `]` excluding `^` of course.

The problem maybe comes from the way you interpret the result provided by `test()`. Here if the regex matches the string `linkTitle`, and `test` returns true; this means you got a wrong char in the input (neither a capital letter, nor in lower case, not a digit and not a space).

Have tested your regexs :

```
/[^A-Za-z\d\s]/.test('0 '); // no match, false, input is ok
/[^A-Za-z\d\s]/.test('0 $'); // match, true, input is wrong
```

Comment: appreciate the response but i do understand the NOT operator and am clear with my conditional action based on it..

Comment: ok, but so what is wrong with your example. Don't you want to detect any wrong char in the input ? All three regex behave the same way, and they work.